# Powershell Script to clean up logs on a Monthly Basis

Tags: powershell, archive

Powershell newbie here again with another question.

We currently have a log folder accumulating text files. My supervisor would like for me to create a script where only the current month's logs are visible. All previous months should be moved to an archive folder. He would like for me to create a powershell script we can run once a month to achieve this.

For example, our log folder should only have logs from January 2021. Anything older than January 2021 should be archived. Once February 1, 2021 hits, all the logs from January 2021 should be moved to the archive folder, and so on.

How can I achieve a script that looks at the folder and only keeps the logs for the current month? Any guidance, resources, videos, etc are greatly appreciated! I've been scouring the internet for resources, but I haven't quite found anything that suits my needs.

**Update:** Was able to find a wonderful script here: [PowerShell: Sort and Move Files by Date to month and year](https://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2015/03/move-files-to-folder-sorted-by-year-and-month-with-powershell/) provided by Thomas Maurer (all credit to him!)

```
# Get the files which should be moved, without folders
$files = Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\log' -Recurse | where {!$_.PsIsContainer}
 
# List Files which will be moved
$files
 
# Target Filder where files should be moved to. The script will automatically create a folder for the year and month.
$targetPath = 'C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\log\archive'
 
foreach ($file in $files)
{
# Get year and Month of the file
# I used LastWriteTime since this are synced files and the creation day will be the date when it was synced
$year = $file.LastWriteTime.Year.ToString()
$month = $file.LastWriteTime.Month.ToString()
 
# Out FileName, year and month
$file.Name
$year
$month
 
# Set Directory Path
$Directory = $targetPath + "\" + $year + "\" + $month
# Create directory if it doesn't exsist
if (!(Test-Path $Directory))
{
New-Item $directory -type directory
}
 
# Move File to new location
$file | Move-Item -Destination $Directory
}
```

**What I would like to achieve now**: This script works great, but I am trying to tinker with it so I can move everything EXCEPT the current month. I'm still researching and investigating, so I will make sure to update my post if I am able to figure out this missing piece for me. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Normally I'd say this question is way too broad and that you should break down the problem into more specific problems with details of what you've tried etc, but I wrote a script a few months back that basically does this. It's [Archiver on PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Archiver/1.0), and the [source is available with an MIT license](https://github.com/zzzzBov/archiver-ps/blob/main/Archiver/Archiver.psm1) if you want to make your own version.

Comment: **_there are AT LEAST thousands of scripts that do what you describe - and many are available on the inet._** [*grin*] have you searched for any such? what did not work as expected? what errors did you get?

Comment: Thank you @zzzzBov for the links! I will take a look at them as I think it might have my missing piece in excluding the current month :) I appreciate the resources!

Comment: Hi @Lee_Dailey - you're absolutely right, I admit I posted this in a bit of a panic as I was still searching for possible solutions. I have updated my post with a script I was able to find created by Thomas Maurer, which has helped with my question :) At the moment, I'm trying to figure out how to exclude the current month. I'm reviewing the resources provided by the previous commenter and hoping I can piece it together.

Comment: @CPG - to filter out the files in the current month, you need to decide how to define "current month". [*grin*] one way is to use the `.Month` property of the datetime objects in question. another is to use `.AddDays(-30)` to get a date that is 30 days old and then use that for your filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to leave the files that were last modified in this month is to use a small helper function that formats the LastWriteTime date into a string `yyyy\MM`.

```
function Format-YearMonth ([datetime]$date) {
    # simply output a string like "2021\01"
    return '{0:yyyy\\MM}' -f $date
}

$sourcePath = 'C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\log'
$targetPath = 'C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\log\archive'
$thisMonth  = Format-YearMonth (Get-Date)

# Get the files which should be moved, without folders 
# this can be more efficient if all files have the same extension on which
# you can use -Filter '*.log' for instance.
Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -File -Recurse | 
    # filter out the files that have a LastWriteTime for this year and month
    Where-Object {(Format-YearMonth $_.LastWriteTime) -ne $thisMonth } |
    ForEach-Object {
        # Set destination Path
        $Directory = Join-Path -Path $targetPath -ChildPath (Format-YearMonth $_.LastWriteTime)
        # Create directory if it doesn't exsist
        if (!(Test-Path $Directory)) {
            $null = New-Item $Directory -type Directory
        }
        Write-Host "Moving file '$($_.FullName)' to '$Directory'"
        # Move File to new location
        $_ | Move-Item -Destination $Directory -Force
    }
```